# wp_redirect and get variables

Tags: wp-redirect

I'm using wp_redirect to send the user back to an admin page.
Everything works fine expect for the get variable that gets removed for some reason.

```
    $url = "admin.php?page=cv_data&saved";
    wp_redirect(admin_url($url));
```

Redirects fine to

`admin.php?page=cv_data&saved`

half a second later the url loses the "saved" variable.

`admin.php?page=cv_data`

I was trying to use that "saved" get variable to trigger some CSS and give some feedback to the user that the form was saved.

I tried giving the variable a value like &saved=1. Still lose it.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I got it working.

Even though the URL loses the GET variable, its still set and working. A simple if(isset($_GET["saved"])) returns true and I can keep doing what i intended.

The fact that the variable appears and disappears in seconds from the URL confused me.

¯|_(ツ)_|¯